# Display php error on page

Tags: php

I have a page named `error.php` and want to show all `php` errors in a table, each error in a row. exactly what display in the error.log file in root.

I used this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

And it let show all error in browser when open a page, but what I want is display all errors that happen on website on a single page in list format.

I couldn't find a method to `echo` all errors in page, and decided to get all errors from `error.log` file with:

```
file_get_contents('error.log');
```

But It hard to modify data to display correctly, is there a right way to do this?

Comment: `register_shutdown_function(function() { var_dump(error_get_last()); });` configure the anonymous function to suit your needs.

Comment: Aww, I didn't know there is a function to print last errors with `error_get_last()` great, but just a question, why under `register_shutdown_function` ?

Comment: Because error can even occur at the end of line of script. You can just invoke the function without registering it, but I think you should stick to the standards.

Comment: I've consider the same issue with php errors with email reporting.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I tried your code but it just return null, any idea? and it is good to create it as answer.

Comment: Don't expect that `error_get_last()` will get you the parse errors, it is to be used only to get warnings and notices. Try `$_POST[0]` and you will get the expected results.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat so? I don't want this, I want to get all project errors like error_log file.

Answer (score 1):

These can help you:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php

You may use those functions to send errors data to some file, a database, a log service, etc. and retrieve them when requested.

Of course, if there's some fatal error before calling those function, they won't be invoked an the errors won't be registered using your implementation.

Notice also that there's a `php.ini` directive `error_log`.
You may use `ini_get('error_log')`, open the file content (if there's any) and parse the content.